# How to manage fields created with django-primate in django-admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I use django-primate. I override standard user class with 3 new fields:

```
from primate.models import UserBase, UserMeta
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(UserBase):
    __metaclass__ = UserMeta
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='Jon Deg')
    jabber_id = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='jabber@jabber.org')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

And, of course, add admin.py:

```
from primate.admin import UserAdminBase
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserAdmin(UserAdminBase):
    pass

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Now in django-admin I can manage only 'name' and some other standard auth fields. How can I add, for example, jabber_id to django-admin?

Comment: Why don't you just use Profiles, the recommended way of adding new fields to the User model? Then you can register your custom User Admin that inherits from the User Admin (that you unregister), so it shows up in the Django-Admin as well.

Comment: I don't now. django-primate is so beautiful :) Your true. In my situation I can use only Profiles.

Comment: django-primate might appear beautiful, but it's monkey patching. Lemme know if you need help with the Profile thing.